# QGIS 3 broken/disabled python

Tags: python, plugins, qgis, pyqgis

I am encountering major Python issues with QGIS 3.  I was attempting to install 3rd party libraries from OS4GEO shell. Steps are:

1- Run shell as admin; 2- py3_env; 3- pip install scikit-learn

I was getting bugs there so I un-installed QGIS and re-installed it to get a clean slate of python libraries.  When I re-open the newly installed QGIS, I lose python support.  Plugin support is lost and there are no processing options. Uninstalling/Installing QGIS does not solve the problem.  Oddly enough, it is version specific. If I break 3.4, re-installing it does not fix the problem, but I can install 3.10 and 3.15 and they work.  But then if I try to add Python libraries to 3.10, it breaks and a clean install does not solve the problem.

How can I reset the Python for a version, even after using the uninstaller?

Comment: Also filed as https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38449

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a windows system restore and a clean install of any QGIS version. Version 3.10.8 allows external libraries to be installed in the QGIS python 3 environment without more bugs.